# get unread Gmail number

Tags: android, count, gmail

it's me again

This time I'm trying to get the unread email number for gmail and display it on screen.

I'm following the  Gmail Public Labels API and get this code

```
protected int getGmail(Context context) {

    AccountManager.get(context).getAccountsByTypeAndFeatures(ACCOUNT_TYPE_GOOGLE, FEATURES_MAIL,
            new AccountManagerCallback() {
                @Override
                public void run(AccountManagerFuture future) {
                    Account[] accounts = null;
                    try {
                        accounts = future.getResult();//error here
                        if (accounts != null && accounts.length > 0) {
                            String selectedAccount = accounts[0].name;
                            queryLabels(selectedAccount);
                        }

                    } catch (OperationCanceledException oce) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    } catch (AuthenticatorException ae) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
                }
            }, null /* handler */);
```

There is this error:cannot convert from Object to Account[]

The Question is : What do I need to do to remove this error while still getting the results ?